# How do I get a variable name from HTML back into my python

Tags: python, html, django

Hey guys how do I get a variable name from HTML back into my python. So I have this variable {{file}} in my html which I need to pass back into the python file in order the function to work.

Comment: You can not do such a thing. That's not how a HTML request works.

Comment: Could you elaborate more, please? Perhaps show some of your code?

Comment: You need to use a form.

Comment: Sure so I am creating a meme generator. So the first part of the python function gets the user to upload the image they want. The system take to a HTML page which displays the current pic and by using GET request asks the user to type the top and bottom text. The html then submits the form to another python code which prints the following top and bottom text on the image file name.

Comment: OK, so what in that process requires "passing a variable name from HTML to Python"? You seem to have understood the need for forms, so what are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can send variables to the server using methods `POST` or `GET`.
Perhaps you can get the right answer if you elaborate more or showing us some of your code.